# What is the use case of this TensorFlow class: image.flip_up_down?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, image-conversion

What is the use case of this TensorFlow class: image.flip_up_down?
Why the image has to flip up and down? Whats the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Data augmentation is one possible answer. If your training data is not sufficient, we can add more data just by flipping or rotating.